# C# - AutoCompleteTextBox open in my Application.OpenForms

Tags: c#

Basically what I am trying to do is to check if there is other forms open when closing the main form of my application.

I thought I made it with this code :

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count > 1)
        {
            if (!YesNoBox.Show("Title", "Message", this))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
}
```

The `YesNoBox` component is just a classic Yes/No form question and the `.Show()` returns the answer.

It worked quite good until I added some `AutoCompleteTextBox` in my other forms..

When I'm using an `AutoCompleteTextBox`, I fill it with my data when loading the form.

If I click in it, it'll open the list, just like I want, but if I'm closing the form where the `AutoCompleteTextBox` is, it's still appears in my `Application.OpenForms.Count`, [here's an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgVyO.png)

Of course, if I don't interfere with any `AutoCompleteTextBox`, the count will be right.

In this case, I only have my MainForm which is open but my `Application.OpenForms.Count` is 3 so it makes the popup show when closing the MainForm.

I looked at the different members I can find but none of them seems helpful.
I don't know why the `AutoCompleteTextBox` are not closing with their parent.

So, I'm looking for a way to ignore those `AutoCompleteTextBox` in my test, or correctly close them, or anything else if you have a better way yo do it!

Hope you can help me guys!

Thanks.

**EDIT:** `AutoCompleteTextBox` is actually a custom user control that my firm used; you can find the code [here on CodeProject.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16942/AutoComplete-TextBox).

Comment: Very unclear what an "AutoCompleteTextBox" could possibly be.  If it causes Form objects to leak like that then you definitely don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to get count:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[i].Visible == true)
        count++;
}
```

So, you can modify your code to:

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms[i].Visible == true)
            count++;
    }
    if (count > 1)
    {
        if (!YesNoBox.Show("Title", "Message", this))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well! I couldn't find the `Visible` property while debugging and did not think about it..